# How do I perform this special operation with a calculated field in Access?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a Microsoft Access table called `calc1` with fields:

- `calc_ID` (primary key, number)
- `calc` (text)

I have another table called `res1` with:

- `res_ID` (primary key)
- `calc_ID` (number)
- `dimensionbefore` (number)
- `dimensionafter` (number)
- `result` (calculated)

There is a relation, one `calc1` to many `res1`, linking with `calc_ID`.

Is it possible to make the `result` field take its formula from the `calc` field in the `calc1` table?

Example: 
For elongation the field `calc` is

```
([dimensionafter] - [dimensionbefore]) / ([dimensionbefore] * 100)
```

and `calc_ID` is 1.
In the `res1` table if the `calc_ID` is 1 then the result field would take the text from `calc` and make it its formula and return the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query like this:

```
SELECT res1.res_ID, res1.calc_ID, res1.dimensionbefore, res1.dimensionafter,
       Eval(Replace(Replace([calc1].[calc],"[dimensionafter]",[dimensionafter]),"[dimensionbefore]",[dimensionbefore])) AS result
FROM res1 INNER JOIN calc1 ON res1.calc_ID = calc1.calc_ID;
```

The `result` field will return the right calculation result.

Comment: Thanks for helping Scott. Unfortunately I think I need some more guidance. When I paste this query line in "Expression" in the field property of the "result" field in the "res1" table I get a message like this:  The syntax of the subquery in this expression is incorrect. Check the subquery's syntax and enclose the subquery in parentheses. Unfortunately I do not understand what it mean. Is this where I should paste this query line?

Comment: This is an SQL query. You should create a new query, click on "SQL View", delete anything from the query, and then paste the aforementioned SQL statement.

Alternatly, you can create a query in the usual way, adding only the calculated field as follows: `Result: Eval(Replace(Replace([calc1].[calc],"[dimensionafter]",[dimensionafter]),"[dimensionbefore]",[dimensionbefore]))`.

Comment: Thanks so much naftalip, this is fantastic. This is a new way of doing things that will make my database a lot better.